# jQuery - check for index value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to find out what is the `index` value for `th` with class `date`?

```
       <tr>
            <th class="date">Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `.eq(value)` will always return a jQuery object which either contains an element or not, depending on `value`. Or is your question how to find out which value `value` has? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I am a bit confused what you are after here? Are you trying to select the `th` with the class `date` i.e. a simple `table tr th.date` selector, or do you want to know the `class` attribute value for each `th` your selector gets?

Comment: @FelixKling   Basically, I'm looking for way to find out what would be the value of in `eq(value)` for th.date in the following example. I know it would be `eq(0)` but how do find this out with jQuery?

Comment: @Niklas - I'm trying to find out what value would it be in the following `.eq(value)` if I was to use this method for selecting `th.date`. I know it would be eq(0) but how do find this out with jQuery?

Comment: Do you know what [`eq()`](http://api.jQuery.com/eq/) does?

Comment: Ya... applying without knowing sometime leads to danger... better you read that first. http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `$("table").find("th").eq(0)`  for selecting the first 'th' of table. [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yFvd7/1/)

Update : now I have updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egY2C/) too.

```
$("th").each(function(index) {
    if($(this).attr('class') == "date") {
        alert(index);
    }
});
```